# Am I reinventing the wheel? PHP/Mysql User reigstration and payment processing

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, user-interface, payment-gateway

I'm about to code a php/mysql platform that does the following:

- Admin panel
- User registration
- Paypal payment processing
- Paypal subscription handling via api so that the user doesnt have to have a paypal account

Does something like this already exist that I can use?

If nothing exists like this, I'm going to code it fresh in the zend framwork, something that I've never used before. If I go this route, will parts of what I'm doing should I not reinvent?

Edit: DEFINITELY SHOULD HAVE POSTED THIS FIRST:

The reason why I need this platform is just a base for me to create php web-based business applications that the customers have to maintain a monthly subscription to use. I'm looking for something VERY lightweight. This is just the platform to handle registrations and subscriptions and paymnents, not the entire website. This will not be a store in an oscommerce sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An object-oriented PHP5 framework engineered to integrate easily with the Website Payments Pro API from Paypal. Complete the DoDirectPayment, SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment operations in just 3 lines or less.**

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/phppaypalpro/version-0.2.1/phpPaypalPro-0.2.1/phppaypalpro-0.2.1.2.rar?use_mirror=ignum

Answer (score 2):

This one is the best of all   [Oxid eshop](http://www.oxid-esales.com/de/download/open-source-software-oxid-eshop-community-edition)

```
*** Written in PHP
* Object-oriented code
* 90+% Unit Test coverage
* Licensed under GPL v3
* 5+ years market track record**
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ecommerce applications out there written using PHP/MySQL. Try something like [a wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) or [quick e-commerce](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Quick-ECommerce-with-PHP-and-PayPal/) or Google.  There's a bunch of them.

Answer (score 1):

check out OSCommerce. It may be overkill for what you need, or it may not. Also check out Drupal if you are more interested in a content based subscription. I think they have a subscription user account module.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are reinventing the wheel. Although im not familiar with implementing paypal stuff, there are for sure applications in php/mysql which provide you some kind of admin panel (dont know what you're looking for) and also user registration is nothing special.

Try something like Joomla with a plugin for paypal, i guess it will exist.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend that you check out a CMS like Joomla (which I hated a year ago when I checked it out), Drupal or even WordPress (yes, it's a CMS and not just a blog). Any of them will have UserRegistration and will run on MySql. In addition, payment processing can be done through a plugin: there are tons available on all of these platforms, some free and some pay.

Coding it yourself will be expensive. On the other hand, if you do decide to code it yourself, study existing plugins thoroughly so you know what functionality to include (or not include in the first version).